# Feynman Vertex Rule, Correlator, 2 diff coupling constants, why no-cross terms

Tags: physics, quantum-field-theory

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

Vertex Feynamnn rule for computing the time correlator of fields under an action such as, for example,

Say $S_{int} [\phi] =\int d^4 x \lambda \frac{\phi^4(x)}{4!} + g \frac{\phi^4(x)}{4!} $, $\lambda$ and $g$ the coupling constants.

2. Relevant equations

see below

3. The attempt at a solution

The solution is the usual a vertex rule for $\lambda$ like interactions with  and a separate vertex rule for $g $ like interactions I don’t get why there is no vertex rule for a combined $\lambda g $ like interaction- please see my working below:

$S_{int} [\phi] =\int d^4 x \lambda \frac{\phi^4(x)}{4!} + g \frac{\phi^4(x)}{4!} $, $\lambda$ and $g$ the coupling constants. (apologies signs are probably wrong here , please ignore)

Say I am evaluating $\langle 0|T(\phi(x)\phi(y))|0\rangle  $ T the time- correlator function.

By Dyson’s formula I am to look at

$ _0 \langle  0 | T(\phi_0(x)\phi_0(y)) \int^{\infty}_{\infty}e^\frac{-1}{h}  dt \ H_{int} (t)   |0\rangle _0 $ Where the underscore 0 denotes free-field theory. ($h$ is $h/2\pi$ apologies).

(only need to look at this rather than normalising it also and computed the correlators of the normalisation by noting that ‘bubble’ diagrams will cancel).

Expanding out the exponential I am looking at:

$ _0 \langle  0 | T(\phi_0(x)\phi_0(y)) \int^{\infty}_{\infty}e^\frac{-i}{h}  dt H_{int} (t)   |0\rangle _0 $

Now let me look at the 2nd term from the exponential expansion. I have, dropping the factorial constants:

$\iint  dz_1 dz_2 0_ \langle  0 | T(\phi_0(x)\phi_0(y)) ( \lambda \phi_0^4(z_1)  + g \phi_0^4(z_1)) .  ( \lambda \phi_0^4(z_2)  + g \phi_0^4(z_2))     |0\rangle _0 $

= sole $\lambda^2 $ term + sole $g^2$ term + $2\lambda g \iint  dz_1 dz_2 \langle  0 | T(\phi_0(x)\phi_0(y)) ( \lambda \phi_0^4(z_1)   \lambda \phi_0^4(z_2)   |0\rangle _0 $

Which, as far as I can see, I can apply Wicks theorem to get:

$\iint dz_1 dz_2 G(x-y) = G(x-z_1)G(y-z_2)G(z_1-z_3)^3$

Where $G(x-y) $ is the propagator.

For the case where there are two different fields, a field for each interaction term, it is clear that there would be no cross terms since you can’t contract fields of a different type. However in this case I don’t understand why there is no vertex rule for cross $\lambda g$ terms.

Comment: 1) math involved in diagrammatica is more physics than math. 2) you action looks really strange to the point it is probably wrong. 3) when you translate a QFT question to math question, please use God's given unit, $\hbar = c = 1$.

Comment: My action is probably wrong, to be honest I wanted an example which would yield a fully connected diagram associated to the cross-term, as I am after the general concept- i.e not that there is no rule associated with a 'cross-term vertex' just because such an interaction would yield only disconnected graphs which may be discarded.  I initially had a phi^3 + phi^4 term, however at second order of the exponential expansion, and with a two field correlatator, this yielded only disconnected graphs.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now, cross-terms are allowed I misinterpreted, however, when you expand out the quadratic order of the exponential term, since the internal vertices are integrated over you get 2$\lambda g $ so wouldn't the symmetry rules                       (or the vertex rule ) for such interactions need to be slightly modified to account for this factor of 2? many thanks